# Force OpenMP to not cache a large object in each thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am writing a C++ program with a loop that I am trying to parallelize using OpenMP. The loop I am writing has the following structure:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    result[i] = work_func(left[i], right[i], largeObject);
```

The `largeObject` argument is marked as a constant reference. My issue is that when I move from a single thread to many threads (~40), the memory usage dramatically increases. The `left` and `right` arguments are both small, meaning that even completely copying them to all threads would not account for the memory increase.

I would like to tell OpenMP to not copy `largeObject` to all of the threads local cache, instead forcing it to use a single global copy. Is there any way of doing this? This seems to go against the no false-sharing optimizations that are more common with OpenMP performance issues. I am less concerned with runtime slowdown than with the large memory overhead of this program.

Thanks!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198997/openmp-running-with-all-threads-in-parallel-leads-to-out-of-memory-exceptions?rq=1) seems to be encountering a similar issue, but the answer does not seem helpful...

Comment: Are you sure that `work_func` internally isn't making the copy, or allocating big chunks of memory for something else?

Comment: Hmm that would be a reasonable explanation, but I've just double-checked and ```work_func``` and all functions it calls takes in ```largeObject``` as a constant reference. I'll keep looking but I don't think that's the issue

Comment: In addition, the function does allocate a small amount of memory, but even all of these allocations in all threads would not account for the memory increase.

Comment: Have you tried to fine-tune Memory Management Directives ( in API Specification: para 2.11 ) for OpenMP Memory Spaces ( in 2.11.1, Tab. 2.8 ) + omp_init_allocator ( in 3.7.2 ). Also the actual code for the *work_func()* would tell more on this subject, depending on how the *largeObject* data gets accessed / computed with.

Comment: did you try to declare you `largeObject` as `volatile`? Normally, this keyword is meant to avoid storing some data in cache, which is what you want here. That said, I highly doubt that your memory consumption issue comes from data caching. Caching is done at the processor's level and the size is fixed by hardware. It shouldn't affect the central memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

`int` **`const`** `largeObject`-declaration directive shall advocate the compilation-phase to avoid any ***sharing*** add-on mechanics and/or synchronisation tactics for a principally un-mutable object (as there are no race conditions that can appear for none ever present write-attempt(s) that would need an access the declared un-mutable `const largeObject`. Using `volatile` directive, as mentioned by @Gilles, uses another, compiler-injected value-access strategy mechanisms, that are not directly related to the OpenMP, but are respected by the respective `omp`-section(s) ).

```
#include <iostream>                                                                
#include <omp.h>                                                                   

#define anIndeedLargeSIZE 2
int main()                                                                         
{   
    int               largeObject[anIndeedLargeSIZE] = {0};
    #pragma omp const largeObject

    std::cout << "largeObject address " << largeObject << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();                                         

        std::cout << "tid: " << tid << " :: " << largeObject << std::endl;

        if (i == tid)
        {   
         // largeObject[i] = tid; // const .... un-mutable mode
            std::cout << "tid: " << tid << " :: now reading and using a const largeObject[" << (int)i << "] == " << largeObject[i] << std::endl;
            }

        }

    std::cout << "largeObject processing FINISHED." << std::endl;

    return 0;                                                                   
    }
```

Please test the memory-allocation side-effects for indeed large sizes, which the IDE-prototyped code was not fair to test at the [Godbolt site IDE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NRQSQ_) <sub>( the full MCVE-code for further experimentation and extensions profiling present altogether with compiler options used [there](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NRQSQ_) )</sub> as the OpenMP API Documentation warns, that the **actual behaviour is *"implementation specific"***.

[image]

```
(base) Wed Jan 08 00:00:00 @64FX:~/$ g++ -o largeObject_const_OMP -O3 -fopenmp largeObject_const_OMP.c
largeObject_const_OMP.c: In function ‘int main()’:
largeObject_const_OMP.c:65:30: error: expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause before ‘const’
     #pragma omp parallel for const (largeObject) num_threads(2)

<--------------------code-revised-as-desired-by-parsing-error:65:30:expected ‘#pragma omp’ clause ADDED before ‘const’-->
(base) Wed Jan 08 00:00:00 @64FX:~/$ g++ -o largeObject_const_OMP -O3 -fopenmp largeObject_const_OMP.c
<--------------------no-error-message|warning-from-parse|compile|link-phases-HERE->
(base) Wed Jan 08 00:00:00 @64FX:~/$ ./largeObject_const_OMP
largeObject address 0x7fff81b97d58
tid: tid: 0 :: 10x7fff81b97d58 :: 
tid: 0 :: now reading and using a const largeObject[0] == 0
0x7fff81b97d58
tid: 1 :: now reading and using a const largeObject[1] == 0
largeObject processing FINISHED.
```

---

### Accessing `int const` v/s `int volatile` **`largeObject`** :

```
#include <iostream>                                                  // >>> https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NRQSQ_
#include <omp.h>                                                     // >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637163/force-openmp-to-not-cache-a-large-object-in-each-thread/59638455?noredirect=1#comment105445758_59638455

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define  anIndeedLargeSIZE 2
int main()
{   
 //
                  int const largeObject[anIndeedLargeSIZE] = {0};
 // #pragma       omp const largeObject                              // largeObject_const_OMP.c:46:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp const [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    std::cout << "int const largeObject address[_" << largeObject << "_]" << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 * tid ) );

        std::cout << "tid: " << (int)tid << " ::[_" << largeObject << "_]" << std::endl;

        if (i == tid)
        {   
         // largeObject[i] = tid; // const .... un-mutable mode
            std::cout << "tid: " << (int)tid << " :: now reading and using an int const largeObject[" << (int)i << "] == " << largeObject[i] << std::endl;
            }

        }

    std::cout << "int const largeObject[] processing FINISHED." << std::endl;
    /*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    >>> ~/$ ./largeObject_const_OMP
    *  int const largeObject address[_0x7fff3ed0db28_]
    *  tid: 0 ::[_0x7fff3ed0db28_]
    *  tid: 0 :: now reading and using an int const largeObject[0] == 0
    *  tid: 1 ::[_0x7fff3ed0db28_]
    *  tid: 1 :: now reading and using an int const largeObject[1] == 0
    *  int const largeObject[] processing FINISHED.
    * 
    *  */

 /*
                  int volatile largeObject[anIndeedLargeSIZE] = {0};
    std::cout << "int volatile largeObject address[_" << largeObject << "_]" << std::endl;

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 * tid ) );

        std::cout << "tid: " << (int)tid << " ::[_" << largeObject << "_]" << std::endl;

        if (i == tid)
        {   
         // largeObject[i] = tid; // const .... un-mutable mode
            std::cout << "tid: " << (int)tid << " :: now reading and using an int volatile largeObject[" << (int)i << "] == " << largeObject[i] << std::endl;
            }

        }

    std::cout << "int volatile largeObject[] processing FINISHED." << std::endl;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    >>> ~/$ ./largeObject_const_OMP
    *  int volatile largeObject address[_1_]
    *  tid: 0 ::[_1_]
    *  tid: 0 :: now reading and using an int volatile largeObject[0] == 0
    *  tid: 1 ::[_1_]
    *  tid: 1 :: now reading and using an int volatile largeObject[1] == 0
    *  int volatile largeObject[] processing FINISHED.
    * */
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Never heard about this `omp const` directive. Didn't find it on [the OpenMP standard](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmp.html) an neither GCC 9.2.0, nor Intel compiler 2019u5 recognise it... `const.cc:8: warning: ignoring #pragma omp const`
You sure about that?

Comment: @Gilles ***Fact a)*** g++ compilation did not object a single word of complaint or warning (output added above) ***Fact b)*** OpenMP v5.0 Nov-2018 Documentation, [page 271] (row 26+) state *"Variables with **const**-qualified type with no mutable members may be listed in firstprivate clause, even if they are static data members"*, which we do not want ( for the firstprivate memory impacts, yet the rest of the said notation was used and compilation went as noted sub *a)* ).

Comment: Did you try g++ with `-Wunknown-pragmas`? By default, unknown pragmas aren't signaled by GCC.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/I36Ght which is your link with only `-Wunknown-pragmas` added to the compiler options gives indeed the message that the `#pragma omp const` is unknown and thus ignored.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, can confirm the g++ warning. Thank you for your care. With **int const largeObject address[_0x7fff3ed0db28_]** the behaviour and the addresses of values to access remain the same as above, with **int volatile largeObject address[_1_]** the referenced addresses to access the here volatile values have changed to but [_1_]. How will this work for indeed large BLOBs?